# SQLAlchemy: How to do time_created and time_modified correctly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using this as a standard to my models:

```
class Element(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    time_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, onupdate=func.now())
```

Unfortunately `time_updated` is not set at creation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Would it be enough to also set the `server_default=func.now()` for `time_updated`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to set a server_default for time_updated as well. Does this work?

```
class Element(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    time_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
```